# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode in Mac OS X ipython notebook

Tags: macos, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Im running a notebook which has a pandas dataFrame. 
when I try to `print df`, it works fine.

When I just try to evaluate `df` in a single ipython notebook cell, so it will prettily (HTML) print the dataframe, I get the error:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 32164: ordinal not in range(128)`

BTW, that df is the result of filtering on a different dataFrame, such that `df = old_df[old_df['column1']='someval']`

Evaluating on `old_df` works fine. 
I'm guessing, after filtering, the values in df that are at the start, and therefore are displayed are the problematic ones.

How can I solve that?